# How do you hide the cursor prior to touching or clicking anywhere within the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a cursor animation that expands and returns to being small.

This would be for a touchscreen, so I'm looking to have the cursor only show whenever a user touches the screen.

I looked at something like this but it didn't work:

```js
window.addEventListener('touchstart', () => { 
    // set your cursor
    document.classList.add('cursor');
});
window.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
    // remove the cursor
    document.classList.remove('cursor');
});
```

Here is the code for the cursor animation:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: "+(e.pageY - 10)+"px; left: "+(e.pageX - 10)+"px;")
        })

        document.addEventListener('click', () => {
            cursor.classList.add("expand");

            setTimeout(() => {
                cursor.classList.remove("expand");
            }, 500)
        });
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are we talking about the _actual_ cursor here, or something you implemented yourself (some HTML element that moves across the screen) …? Because with the actual cursor, I don’t understand what the question would be here in the first place, when would that show on a touch screen?

Comment: Can you make a working snippet see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - in particular we need to see what your class 'cursor' does. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the OP to add the cursor animation code.
You click and there's an expanding circles effect.

Comment: I want to the effect to simply work within the browser, so doesn't need to be a touchscreen. How to have the initial cursor hidden then appear whenever clicked.